# Installation of VS code on RaspPi to be used with openhab2

Tags: raspberry-pi, visual-studio-code, openhab

I just tried to install VS code and the openhab extension via this site (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) and followed all the steps until "sudo apt-get install code-insiders". Then it failed.

It tells me: Package code-insiders cannot be found.

Any ideas? Do I need to insert a code number?

Furthermore, how can I install the required openhab2 extension? I don´t find the required add-on in the selection menus.

Thanks for your help, 
db

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Visual Studio, you probably did so by downloading the package and installing it directly, instead of following their instructions for including Microsoft's repository on your system. Or maybe there was a hiccup when you followed their instructions, and something didn't get installed correctly.

You have two choices.  You can include Microsoft's repo in your apt by [following their instructions here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) (refer to the section under Debian titled "The repository and key can also be installed manually with the following script:"), or you can [download the code-insiders package from here](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and install it manually.  (I'd recommend the first option, as Microsoft should be a trustworthy company to add into your apt repository list.)